# First DIV has a different style than the rest

Tags: html, css

I have a list of DIVs that share the same classes as follows:

```
<div class="content1"><div class="contentInner">Text1</div></div>
<div class="content1"><div class="contentInner">Text2</div></div>
<div class="content1"><div class="contentInner">Text3</div></div>
...
```

I want the first DIV with class="content1" to have a different style than the following DIVs of the same class. What is the CSS selector that can accomplish this?
Thanks

Comment: you could add: id="specificdiv1" to the first div. 
Then in CSS you can use: #specificdiv1 to address it. 

You can have class and id in same div.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for first element with class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `nth-of type` selector**.

```
.content1:nth-of-type(1){
  /* your style */
}
```

Using `first-child` only works if there is no sibling element before your desired div.

[See fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/e1xbkzL9/)

Answer (score 1):

CSS has a pseudo selector which is used in such scenario where you need to select the first element from similar elements i.e. [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child)

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the first child element of its parent.

Example:

```
div.content1:first-child{

  /* your css */
}
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bdxp8y4p/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `:not` and `:first-child` pseudo selector of CSS to give specific css to the first div.

**Example:**

```
.content1:not(:first-child) {
    /* Common CSS for all divs except first div */
}

.content1:first-child {
    /* CSS for first div */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the :first-child selector. e.g

```
.content1:first-child{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yurszzoc/)